# why class not render after set state in react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to add an active class to the indicator after clicking it but the active class doesn't render even though list.id === active

```
const [active, setActive] =  useState(1);

const scrollToElement = (id, value) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(`${value}`);
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

    setActive(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        active: id
      }
    });
  }
  
<div
  key={list.id}
  className={`${list.id === active ? `${style.active} ${style.dot}` : `${style.dot}`}`}
  onClick={() => scrollToElement(list.id, list.name)}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are returning an object for a new state value.

Try this:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(1);

const scrollToElement = (id, value) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(`${value}`);
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

    setActive(id);
}

<div
    key={list.id}
    className={`${list.id === active ? `${style.active} ${style.dot}` : `${style.dot}`}`}
    onClick={() => scrollToElement(list.id, list.name)}
/>
```